# Show that the path components $\pi_0$ of $X = U \cup V$ form a pushout diagram.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

[image]

By the definition, I'd need to show that:
$\bullet$ the diagram commutes, and
$\bullet$ if $Z$ is a space and if $F': \pi_0(U) \to Z$ and $G': \pi_0(V) \to Z$ are maps such that 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\pi_0( U \cap V) @>{f}>> \pi_0(V)\\
@V{g}VV @VV{G'}V\\
\pi_0(U) @>{F'}>> Z
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, then there exists a unique map $h: \pi_0( U \cup V) \to Z $ such that $F'=h\circ F$ and $G'=h\circ G$.

For the first property, my idea is to specify the maps in the original diagram to be those that send the elements to their respective path components. But I don't see how to go about showing the second property.

---

Comment: You have to show that it is a push out of sets, so in your second bullet point you should take Z to be a set. The first bullet point is just proving the functoriality of $\pi_0$. For the second point I suggest you use the universal property to build a map from the colimit to $\pi_0(U\cap V)$ and show that it is an isomorphism using the concrete description of pushouts in Set.

Comment: For you edit: yes, that is what they ask. However, you should just post a new question if you have, well, a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I will attempt it first before asking for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the same names and notation as in your question. As was already pointed out in the comments, $Z$ would just be a normal set since we are considering a pushout in the category of sets.

**For the first part**, to see that the diagram commutes, it is helpful to make precise what the maps do. You have the right idea: when we have an inclusion $A \subseteq B$ of topological spaces, then any path component $C \subseteq A$ will be contained in a unique (possibly larger) path component $C' \subseteq B$ (actually, this is even true when we replace the inclusion with any continuous function, but we won't need that here). This is how the maps $f$, $g$, $F$ and $G$ are defined. In other words, both $Gf$ and $Fg$ are just taking a path component in $U \cap V$ to the unique path component in $U \cup V$ containing it. There are thus the same, and so the diagram commutes.

**For the second part** there is some kind of standard recipe to follow here. It goes roughly as follows:

1. Suppose that a function like $h$ exists.
2. Use the commutativity of the diagram (i.e. $F' = hF$ and $G' = hG$ and so on) to determine how $h$ must be defined.
3. Check that the definition that we found in step 2 actually gives a well-defined map.

Then you are done. Uniqueness follows from step 2 as well: every map that would make everything commute would have to be defined that way.

Note that if you already know how pushouts are calculated in the category of sets, you might be able to take some shortcuts. For example (as suggested in the comments), by constructing a bijection from $\pi_0(U \cup V)$ to this pushout and showing that everything commutes. However, if you do not know how pushouts of sets are calculated then that approach does not help understanding anything. Also, this method works in a lot of categories (e.g. try using it to construct pushouts or products in the category of topological spaces), so it is a nice trick to know.

So, let's try this. Let $C \in \pi_0(U \cup V)$ be some path component in $U \cup V$, what would $h(C)$ need to be? We distinguish two cases:

- $C \cap U \neq \emptyset$, so $C = F(C_U)$ for some $C_U \in \pi_0(U)$. Then we must have $h(C) = hF(C_U) = F'(C_U)$.
- $C \cap V \neq \emptyset$, so $C = G(C_V)$ for some $C_V \in \pi_0(V)$. Then we must have $h(C) = hG(C_V) = G'(C_V)$.

This defines a value for $h$ for all possible $C \in \pi_0(U \cup V)$, but is this well-defined? That is, we could still be defining multiple values for $h(C)$. There are two things we have to check in our definition of $h(C)$.

- What if $C \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $C \cap V \neq \emptyset$?
- What if there are distinct $C_U, C_U' \in \pi_0(U)$ such that $C = F(C_U) = F(C_U')$?

Checking this is a bit tedious, and not very insightful if I spell it out here. So I leave the details to you. What you essentially want to do is define $\sim$ to be the smallest equivalence relation on $\pi_0(U) \amalg \pi_0(V)$ such that $C_U \sim C_V$ (for $C_U \in \pi_0(U)$ and $C_V \in \pi_0(V)$) when $C_U \cap C_V \neq \emptyset$ (so there is $C_{U \cap V} \in \pi_0(C \cap V)$ such that $f(C_{U \cap V}) = C_V$ and $g(C_{U \cap V}) = C_U$). Here you will need that $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$ at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for your second to last bullet point, I'm assuming that you're asking me to verify that $F'(C_U) = G'(C_V) = h(C)$? Please check my attempt at a proof by contradiction: first assume for a contradiction that $F'(C_U) \neq h(C)$. Then there exist $C_1 \in \pi_0(U\cup V), C_1 \neq C$ such that $h(C_1) = F'(C_U)$. Then there exists $C_{1U} \in \pi_0(U), C_{1U} \neq C_U$ such that $F(C_{1U})=C_1$.

Comment: Now if $F'(C_U) = F'(C_{1U})$, then this means $h(F(C_U))=h(F(C_{1U}))$, and $h(C)=h(C_1) =  F'(C_U)$, which contradict the assumption. If on the other hand $F'(C_U) \neq F'(C_{1U})$, then this means $F'(C_U) \neq h(F(C_{1U}))=h(C_1) = F'(C_U)$, which is again a contradiction. So we can't have $F'(C_U) \neq h(C)$. The statement for $G'(C_V)$ is proved similarly. Thus $F'(C_U) = G'(C_V) = h(C)$.

Comment: Irrespective to that proof, could you elaborate how the equivalence relation that you specified fits into the diagram?

Comment: @ensbana For your first question: that is indeed what you have to verify. More precisely, you have to check that $F'(C_U) = G'(C_V)$ so that it does not matter which of the two we use to define $h(C)$. Your proof is not entirely clear to me, mainly because you are already using $h$ as if it is a well-defined function (which is precisely what we are checking here). But let me give you a proof of this part (without using contradiction).

Comment: @ensbana Since $C \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $C \cap V \neq \emptyset$, we have $C \cap U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. So there is some $C_{U \cap V} \in \pi_0(U \cap V)$ such that $f(C_{U \cap V}) = C_V$ and $g(C_{U \cap V}) = C_U$. The commutativity of the outer rectangle then guarantees that $F'(C_U) = F'g(C_{U \cap V}) = G'f(C_{U \cap V}) = G'(C_V)$, as required.

Comment: @ensbana For your second question: suppose we were not asking for a pushout, but just for the coproduct of two sets. Then that is easy, we just take their disjoint union (which I denoted by the symbol $\amalg$ in my answer). You can easily verify that this is indeed a coproduct (do so, because it might give some useful insight). So that is a good place to start, but now we want the inclusion maps from $\pi_0(U)$ and $\pi_0(V)$ into $\pi_0(U) \amalg \pi_0(V)$ to agree on the elements that come from $\pi_0(U \cap V)$. This is exactly what dividing out that equivalence relation does for you.

Comment: @MarkKamsma i'd like to have a question about the first part. In the definition of the pushout that I read, the maps $f$, $g$, $F$ and $G$ are usually given, and taken to be some general maps. Wouldn't explicitly specifying them the way you did sort of affects the generality of the diagram? Or is it the case here that we're arguing that the maps $f$, $g$, $F$ and $G$ defined that way would turn the diagram into a pushout, but they do not exclude the possibility that some other maps might also work?

Comment: @Josh This was a question about specific maps, and whether they form a pushout or not. So the maps are specified (I just recalled their definition in my answer), and show that the square they form is a pushout. You are probably thinking about a statement like "$\pi_0$ preserves pushouts", where we would want to show that any pushout of topological spaces is taken to a pushout of sets. This turns out to be not the case, see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3338561/661457

Comment: This is the definition of the pushout that I have in mind: https://imgur.com/HX0uhGu. The only things we know about the maps $f$, $g$, $F$, $G$ are that they make the "inner" diagram commute and they satisfy the universal property. But we don't know how exactly they look like. So should I interpret the question at the beginning of the thread as "Find $f$, $g$, $F$, $G$ that turn the diagram into a pushout, and verify that fact"?

Comment: @Josh That is the correct definition. And your interpretation of the question is almost correct. The "finding" bit is already done for you here. So it is really just "verify that these $f$, $g$, $F$ and $G$ form a pushout". Now OP did not exactly specify what they are, but to me that was clear from the context.