# Does $\pi_0$ preserve fibered products and effective epimorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, topos-theory

There is an adjunction $$
(\pi_0 \dashv disc): Spaces \rightarrow Set 
$$ 
where $\pi_0$ sends a space to its path components, and $disc$ sends a set to the space with discrete topology.

> (i) Does $\pi_0$ preserve pullback? If not what is a counter example.

I feel this is true. But i've never heard of some saying it preserves finite limits. (We know it preserves products)

*Proof:*  Proof $A\rightarrow B \leftarrow A'$, a map from interval $I$ to the fiber product is identified as the set $\pi_0(A) \times_{\pi_0(B) } \pi_0(A')$ by universal property.

> ii) Does $\pi_0$ preserve [effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism)?

If (i) is true, then as $\pi_0$ commutes with fiber products and colimits it naturally preserves effective epis.

Comment: The adjunction you describe does not actually exist--for instance, if $X$ is totally disconnected but not discrete, then the identity map $\pi_0(X)\to\pi_0(X)$ does not correspond to any continuous map $X\to disc(\pi_0(X))$ (it would correspond to the identity map when you identify $disc(\pi_0(X))$ with $X$ with the discrete topology, but that is not continuous).

Comment: Oh my. For some reason I thought there was an adjunction. Is there one for $\pi_0:Set_\Delta \rightarrow Set$, from simplicial sets to sets?

Comment: Yeah, it does work for simplicial sets.  (Or similarly, it works if you restrict to locally path-connected spaces.)

Comment: I am actually confused now. What is the definition of $\pi_0$ on simplicial sets to have a right adjoint? 


What I know is  we have  the triple $(colim \vdash \Delta \vdash lim): Set \rightarrow Set_\Delta$. On internal category objects (nerve of category) it does take the coequalizier $d_1,d_0:X_1 \rightarrow X_0$, which is what we think to be the path components.

Comment: $\pi_0$ on simplicial sets is usually defined as the coequalizer of $d_0,d_1:X_1\to X_0$.  It is also the same as the colimiit functor from simplicial sets to sets--the subdiagram of a simplicial set consisting of just $d_0,d_1:X_1\to X_0$ has the same colimit as the whole simplicial set (you can see this by either concretely thinking about what the colimits of sets look like, or by checking that the inclusion of this subdiagram is [final](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor)).

Comment: (Note that $(colim \vdash \Delta \vdash lim)$ is backwards: the adjunctions go the other way $(colim \dashv \Delta \dashv lim)$.)

Comment: Yes, that is my bad for the adjunction. And thank you so much, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\pi_0$ preserves neither pullbacks nor effective epimorphisms.  For pullbacks, for instance, consider two maps $f,g:[0,1]\to S^1$ which trace out arcs which are disjoint except at their endpoints.  The pullback is then $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ which is disconnected, but $[0,1]$ and $S^1$ are both path-connected so the pullback after applying $\pi_0$ is just a single point.

For effective epimorphisms, let $X$ be the (closed) topologist's sine curve and let $p:X\to Y$ be the quotient map that collapses the line segment where the sine curve accumulates to a point.  Then $p$ is an effective epimorphism, but $\pi_0(X)$ has two points while $\pi_0(Y)$ has one.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3339247/86856) for more details and related discussion.