# Does the path component functor admit a right adjoint?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Does $\pi_0:Top\to Set$, sending a topological space to its path-connected components, admit a right adjoint?

If not, does it admit a right adjoint if we restrict it to certain topological spaces, say CW complexes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Just embed the discrete spaces so obtained back into Top.

Comment: You might also be interested in knowing that the right adjoint to the discrete topology ha itself a right adjoint (the forget-the-topology functor), which has itself a right adjoint (the codiscrete topology on a set); but that's where the pattern stops :-)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma op is asking for *path* components, so your suggestion breaks down when these are not equal to the connected components.

Comment: @Tyrone why? There is no difference.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma let $\mathcal{S}$ be the topologists sine curve and $A$ discrete. Then $Top(\mathcal{S},A)=A$. On the other hand $Set(\pi_0\mathcal{S},A)=Set(\{0,1\},A)\neq A$ when $|A|>1$. In particular these sets cannot be in (natural) bijective correspondence. (of course this does not discount $\pi_0$ from having some other adjoint).

Comment: @Tyrone It seems you’re right. Then probably there isn’t. This should be well-known, right?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma here is brief argument: left adjoint functors preserve all colimits, but since the path-component functor $\pi_0$ does not, it cannot be a left adjoint. For instance see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338561/show-that-the-functor-pi-0-top-to-set-that-takes-the-path-components-of-t/3339247#3339247)..

Answer (score 6):

As someone mentioned, this can't be done in general, but if we restrict ourselves to locally path connected spaces (in which path components and connected components coincide) $\pi_0$ has a right adjoint.

Let $Top$ denote the category of locally path connected spaces,
define $F: Set \rightarrow Top$ by taking a set $A$ to $A$ with the discrete topology. Since continuous maps preserve connected components, the value of a function
$$f: X \rightarrow A$$
in a connected component is determined by a single point in the component. Thus
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{Top}(X,F(A)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{Set}(\pi_0(X),A).$$

Comment: I think you want locally *path* connected. Note that all CW complexes are locally path connected. On the other hand, if $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex, then its path components are open, but in general $X$ need not be locally path connected.

Comment: Yes of course! I silly mistake, thank you! I'lll correct itm

Comment: Your answer says that on the category $\mathbf{Top_1}$ of spaces with open path components $\pi_0$ has a right adjoint $F$ given by $F(A) = A$ with the discrete top. All locally path connected spaces belong to $\mathbf{Top_1}$, in  particular all CW-complexes. The existence of a right adjoint is no surprise because a space in $\mathbf{Top_1}$  is nothing else than a disjoint union (= sum in $\mathbf{Top}$) of path connected spaces. Note that this representation allows to prove easily that each space homotopy equivalent to a space in $\mathbf{Top_1}$ belongs itself to $\mathbf{Top_1}$.